# Can't open windows arabic txt file in mac os

Tags: windows, macos, encoding

I have Windows txt files with arabic characters, recently I moved to mac and I copied over these txt files to mac os machine, however when I try to open these files in mac os in any of the text editors, it shows me a rubbish like

> ﬂÌ›ﬂ Â»« ‘Ê √Œ»«—ﬂø

I tried to use iconv to change the encode type to utf-8 and utf-16, but it didn't help to get back the arabic characters.

Comment: you have to install the correct fonts on MAC OS probably.

Comment: @Sickest - Mac isn't like Windows in that respect; you don't install language packs, they're all already there - the language recognition itself may need switching on, but I've never had to work with completely non-ascii languages, so this is a bit of a guess. Aladdin - try System Prefs>Language & Region. Click the + sign bottom left & add your required language.